# Total variation distance and couplings

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The total variation distance between two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ can be shown to equal the infimum over all couplings $(X,Y)$ where $X\sim\mu, Y\sim\nu$ of $P(X\neq Y).$ What is the supremum of $P(X\neq Y)$ over all such couplings?

Comment: Is there generally a reason for it not to be $1$?